# How to implement event system in HTML5 Canvas(with transformation?

Tags: canvas, graphics

Suppose I did this:

- save canvas and apply transform, say `A`
- drawing a shape(rectangle, etc.) at point `(x, y)`, give it an id, `"pointer-#{itoa}"`
- (repeat randomly, so that we get a stack of saved canvas states)
- restore canvas state
- repeat randomly

Now there's a click event and I want to find out the ID of that shape which is clicked on. Is there any tool for doing that?

---

I want to mention that I was trying to implement a subset of HTML based on Canvas(project name Quamolit) for better support of transitions. And it becomes a huge problem to find out which element is clicked after some transformations.

Meanwhile I was trying to keep each element in Quamolit described in some scalars (translateX, translateY, rotate, scale) to keep them easy for interpolation.

Comment: There are no objects inside a canvas, just pixels blended together. You have to implement the logic for objects and events yourselves. For events perhaps my [**Eventor**](https://github.com/epistemex/eventor) (one-to-many) or [**Harbour**](https://github.com/epistemex/harbour)  (ports, many-to-one) can help you out on the event part...

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg  I thought "event system" was meaning the whole thing a framework is handling click, and the tough part is after transformation, I can hardly find out which object the clicked pixel is belong to. Eventor seems to be like EventEmitter or something?

Comment: Yes, there are quite a few libraries to assist with keeping track of and "moving" individual drawings on canvas. Keep in mind that individual drawings on canvas cannot really be moved. What happens is that the canvas is cleared and the drawings are redrawn in their newly desired position. Since SO is not meant as a source for library recommendations, you can find many good canvas libs by googling: "html canvas library".

Comment: @markE My desired library is "react-canvas". Unfortunately it does not support transformations yet. I found fabric.js does drag moving.. I'll look into that later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas draws in a so-called "immediate-mode", it doesn't keep track of painted contents.

But you can use `renderingContext.isPointInPath()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath) to test if a point, i.e. the coordinate of a mouse-click, is within a path. This function must be used while drawing, so using this might not be hassle-free but this is the current way to implement that.
By default `isPointInPath()` uses the zero-number-winding-rule to detect if a point is within a path, which is the same algorithm that is used by the browser to fill a path.

In future there will be HitRegions that should simplify that, but this is not implemented in all browsers yet. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/addHitRegion)

Answer (score 0):

Besides `ctx.isPointInPath()`, I found something called `Hit Region` in specs

http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#hit-regions

and as described on MDN, this is exactly the best solution for telling which path is beging clicked:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/addHitRegion

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){
  if(event.region) {
    alert("ouch, my eye :(");
  }
});

// eyes
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(70, 80, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.arc(130, 80, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fill();
ctx.addHitRegion({id: "eyes"});
```

One may specify an `id` to each path. While clicking, that id will be sent back with `event`.

Bad news is this APIs is not fully supported in any browser. Chrome and Firefox support the basic part of that.